# Flexdashboard horizontal scroll bar with DataTable

Tags: r, datatable, r-plotly, flexdashboard

I am trying to make a dashboard with a plotly chart in one column and a datatable in the other.

I need the chart to be bigger than the DT, but the DT is overriding the size of the plotly.

Here is an example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
runtime: shiny
---

<style> #dt{ overflow: auto; } </style>   


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
diamonds <-  diamonds[1:20,]
```



Column {data-width=900}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Chart A 
```{r}
plot_ly(diamonds,
        x = ~ cut,
        y = ~ price,
        color = ~ clarity)
```

### Chart B 
```{r}
dt <- datatable(diamonds ,options = list(c(scrollY="200px", scrollX=TRUE, pageLength = 100)),  filter = 'top')
dt
````

I have been experimenting with different ways to specify the data-width, but none have worked so far.

Does anyone have any insight on how I can get the datatable to have a horizontal scrollbar? Is this possible with flexdashboard?

For example, I would like for the datatable to only show a few columns and the user can scroll to see the rest, so that the graph will be the main focus of the dashboard.

Comment: While I realize this doesn't totally solve your issue, it does seem to work when setting the `vertical_layout:` to `fill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your code a little and I think the version below is what you are after. I changed the following:

1. Removed the "orientation: rows" line from your header definition.

2. Separated the charts into 2 individual columns.

3. Changed the "vertical_layout: scroll" to "vertical_layout: fill" as per Thomas John Flahertys comment above.

The code now reads:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
 ---

<style> #dt{ overflow: auto; } </style>   


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
diamonds <-  diamonds[1:20,]
```



Column {data-width=300}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Chart A 
```{r}
plot_ly(diamonds,
        x = ~ cut,
        y = ~ price,
        color = ~ clarity)
```

Column {data-width=100}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Chart B 
```{r}
dt <- datatable(diamonds ,options = list(c(scrollY="200px", scrollX=TRUE, pageLength = 100)),  filter = 'top')
dt
```
````

Comment: This is a helpful workaround, I was hoping to be able to use the scrolling layout because I will have other charts to add below these two and scrolling would make sense for the visualization.

Comment: I only use flex dashboard if I need a really simple page. For any thing complex I use shiny dashboard. Might be worth looking at if you're not already familiar with it.